# Buffer overflow needs 16 bytes on x86 but 29 bytes on x64

Tags: c, security, stack, x86-64, buffer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char buff[15];
  int auth = 0;

  printf("\nEnter password: ");
  gets(buff);

  if (strcmp(buff, "password") != 0) {
    printf("\nAccess denied\n");
  } else {
    auth = 1;
  }

  if (auth) {
    printf("\nAccess granted\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This piece of code needs 16 bytes (characters input by the user) to overflow `auth` on x86 and print "Access granted". On x64, 29 bytes are required to do the same. Why is this? It seems like there is either some padding going on between my variables or there's an address for something else in between them. I don't believe this is the effect of shadow space (does this apply on *nix too?) since only the first 32 bytes are reserved https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention

Note that I'm not compiling this with any optimizations to avoid things being inside of a register.

I'm on OS X using GCC 6.2.0. This is the assembly output for the x86 version:

```
    .cstring
LC0:
    .ascii "\12Enter password: \0"
LC1:
    .ascii "password\0"
LC2:
    .ascii "\12Access denied\0"
LC3:
    .ascii "\12Access granted\0"
    .text
    .globl _main
_main:
LFB1:
    pushl   %ebp
LCFI0:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
LCFI1:
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $36, %esp
LCFI2:
    call    ___x86.get_pc_thunk.bx
L1$pb:
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    subl    $12, %esp
    leal    LC0-L1$pb(%ebx), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    _printf
    addl    $16, %esp
    subl    $12, %esp
    leal    -27(%ebp), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    _gets
    addl    $16, %esp
    subl    $8, %esp
    leal    LC1-L1$pb(%ebx), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    leal    -27(%ebp), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    _strcmp
    addl    $16, %esp
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  L2
    subl    $12, %esp
    leal    LC2-L1$pb(%ebx), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    _puts
    addl    $16, %esp
    jmp L3
L2:
    movl    $1, -12(%ebp)
L3:
    cmpl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    je  L4
    subl    $12, %esp
    leal    LC3-L1$pb(%ebx), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    _puts
    addl    $16, %esp
L4:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    -4(%ebp), %ebx
    leave
LCFI3:
    ret
LFE1:
    .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
    .weak_definition    ___x86.get_pc_thunk.bx
    .private_extern ___x86.get_pc_thunk.bx
___x86.get_pc_thunk.bx:
LFB2:
    movl    (%esp), %ebx
    ret
LFE2:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x7c
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x5
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x88
    .byte   0x1
    .align 2
LECIE1:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .long   LFB1-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE1-LFB1
    .long L$set$2
    .byte   0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB1
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x84
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xd
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$5,LCFI2-LCFI1
    .long L$set$5
    .byte   0x83
    .byte   0x3
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$6,LCFI3-LCFI2
    .long L$set$6
    .byte   0xc4
    .byte   0xc3
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x5
    .byte   0x4
    .align 2
LEFDE1:
LSFDE3:
    .set L$set$7,LEFDE3-LASFDE3
    .long L$set$7
LASFDE3:
    .long   LASFDE3-EH_frame1
    .long   LFB2-.
    .set L$set$8,LFE2-LFB2
    .long L$set$8
    .byte   0
    .align 2
LEFDE3:
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

And for the x64 version:

```
    .cstring
LC0:
    .ascii "\12Enter password: \0"
LC1:
    .ascii "password\0"
LC2:
    .ascii "\12Access denied\0"
LC3:
    .ascii "\12Access granted\0"
    .text
    .globl _main
_main:
LFB1:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -36(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -48(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    _printf
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _gets
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    leaq    LC1(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _strcmp
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  L2
    leaq    LC2(%rip), %rdi
    call    _puts
    jmp L3
L2:
    movl    $1, -4(%rbp)
L3:
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    je  L4
    leaq    LC3(%rip), %rdi
    call    _puts
L4:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
LCFI2:
    ret
LFE1:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x78
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .byte   0x1
    .align 3
LECIE1:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB1-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE1-LFB1
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB1
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x86
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xd
    .byte   0x6
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$5,LCFI2-LCFI1
    .long L$set$5
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: `gets()` is not part of C. Consider changing the tag. If the string does not fit into the buffer, the behavior is *undefined*. If you enable optimizations, chances are that `auth` will be register-allocated and *never* clobbered at all.

Comment: Isn't it a library function? And yes, you're right. I'm just looking to understand why 14 more bytes are needed past the buffer to overflow the int on x64. I'll update my question to clarify about optimization.

Comment: `gets()` has the ignoble distinction of being so bad it was *removed from C* (which otherwise worships compatibility to the point of trigraphs). My point is that there is very little to be gained by asking this question, since the behavior is not required to be consistent in any way.

Comment: x86 and x64 have different architectures - data sizes, etc.  Why would you expect the same *undefined* behavior in the first place?

Comment: `char buff[15];` actually needs only `15` characters input to overflow, since `gets` also stores a nul terminator. Whether or not any damage is incurred at that point... is undefined behaviour. So I can't understand what you need to be explained.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm just trying to understand where the 14 extra bytes is coming from. Assuming all of the pointers are 8 bytes and the stack is 16 byte aligned on x64 I would have expected to see `buff` padded to 16 bytes and then have the `auth` immediately overflowable afterwards.

Comment: @WeatherVane yup, you're right. The 16th character is what overflows `auth` on x86 which is what I'm focusing on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess the OP is just trying to understand what are those differences and how is the x86_64 stack layout in comparison to the x86. I've debugged this code here too and figured there was an address between the `buff` and `auth` variables. Not sure what is that address, since I'd not expect the return address and saved RBP to be between local variables on the stack. Also, there was an extra byte between the `buff` variable and the mysterious address, which made me wonder if it isn't some sort of padding.

Comment: @IanC you got it! I guess this is more of a "x86 stack vs x64 stack" question. I wrote the code to have undefined behavior just to try and understand what's going on between x86 and x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking about this issue again and remembered about the compiler flag I sent you on chat:

`-mpreferred-stack-boundary=num`

Particularly the following paragraphs:

> Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to num byte boundary.  If -mpreferred-stack-boundary is not specified, **the default is 4 (16 bytes or 128 bits)**.
>
> Warning: When generating code for the x86-64 architecture with SSE extensions disabled, -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 can be used to keep the stack boundary aligned to 8 byte boundary. **Since x86-64 ABI require 16 byte stack alignment, this is ABI incompatible and intended to be used in controlled environment where stack space is important limitation.**

So, the 15 bytes array would require a 16 bytes stack-slot to keep it inside the stack boundary.

The `int auth`, assuming a 4 byte `int`, would also require a 16 bytes stack-slot to respect `gcc`s stack boundary flag. Debugging the program with `gdb`, I noticed the `int auth` address is `BSP-0x04`. `BSP-0x04` up to `BSP-0x10` is padding so it fits the stack-slot. So to overflow the buffer until you reach the `int auth` you would need 15 bytes (buffer size) + 1 byte (buffer padding) + 12 bytes (`int auth` padding) + 1 byte to reach the `int`.

Finally, I mentioned to you I found a address between the array and the `int` while debugging. It's probably some junk leftover on memory: Since the program doesn't care about the extra 12 bytes before the `int`, it probably doesn't clean it and it could have been used to store some memory pointer.

Below there is a representation of the stack of the x64 code program.

#### Main Stack

------------------------------------------------------
<kbd>Saved RBP</kbd>
------------------------------------------------------ New RBP = 0x7FFFFFFFDD10
<kbd>auth</kbd>
------------------------------------------------------ RBP - 0x04 = 0x7FFFFFFFDD0C
<kbd>auth 12 bytes padding</kbd>
------------------------------------------------------ RBP - 0x10 = 0x7FFFFFFFDD00
<kbd>buff 1 byte padding</kbd>
------------------------------------------------------ RBP - 0x11 = 0x7FFFFFFFDCFF
<kbd>buff</kbd>
------------------------------------------------------ RBP - 0x20 = 0x7FFFFFFFDCF0
<kbd>Value of EDI</kbd>
------------------------------------------------------ RBP - 0x24 = 0x7FFFFFFFDCEC
<kbd>Value of RSI</kbd>
------------------------------------------------------ RBP - 0x30 = 0x7FFFFFFFDCE0 <kbd>Top of the Stack</kbd>